# How do i disable bottomAnchor constraint?

Tags: swift, constraints

I tried to disable bottomAnchor constraint but it does not work.

I tried this

```
    myview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = false
```

Comment: This won't work since this code creates a **new** constraint, and doesn't modify or change the existing constraint you are trying to update

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = false
```